# With scikit learn, how to use predict_proba in fit_predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am implementing custom estimators thanks to the scikit library and its Pipeline, BaseEstimators, TransformerMixin and other base classes. ([you can check the API here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html))

Given an pipeline, you can call `pipeline.fit(X)` then `pipeline.predict(X)` or you can use `pipeline.fit_predict(X)` which is a bit faster because it applies necessary transformations once instead of twice (one for the fit and one for the predict). So it is used to get an optimization when you want to predict on the same dataset you used to fit.

But some models, like classifiers or clusterers, have a method called `predict_proba` that return the probability of the classification or labelization.

**From the scikit glossary ([link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html)):**

> **fit_predict**
>
> Used especially for unsupervised, transductive estimators, this fits
>   the model and returns the predictions (similar to predict) on the
>   training data. In clusterers, these predictions are also stored in the
>   labels_ attribute, and the output of `.fit_predict(X)` is usually
>   equivalent to `.fit(X).predict(X)`. The parameters to `fit_predict`
>   are the same as those to `fit`.
>
> **predict_proba**
>
> A method in classifiers and clusterers that are able to return
>   probability estimates for each class/cluster. Its input is usually
>   only some observed data, X.
>
> If the estimator was not already fitted, calling this method should
>   raise a `exceptions.NotFittedError`.
>
> Output conventions are like those for decision_function except in the
>   binary classification case, where one column is output for each class
>   (while decision_function outputs a 1d array). For binary and
>   multiclass predictions, each row should add to 1.
>
> Like other methods, `predict_proba` should only be present when the
>   estimator can make probabilistic predictions (see duck typing). This
>   means that the presence of the method may depend on estimator
>   parameters (e.g. in `linear_model.SGDClassifier`) or training data
>   (e.g. in `model_selection.GridSearchCV`) and may only appear after
>   fitting.

I am looking for a way to get a `fit_predict_proba` method which has the same advantages of the fit_predict but that return probabilities

Comment: I do not think `scikit learn` supports `fit_predict_proba`. I am guessing you must have come across other `alogrithms` outside `scikit learn` which supports `fit_predict_proba`. One way you can tackle this issue would be by writing a custom function which takes the `estimator` and `dataset` as arguments and `fits` then calls a `predict_proba` and returns the output or so.

Comment: Yes but if I do that, i dont get the benefits of `fit_predict`, i'll perform the pipeline transformations twice. For example if i have `Pipeline([preprocessing, clustering])` the preprocessing transformation will happen two times, one time for the `fit` and one time for the `predict_proba`

Comment: Yeap. That is true. But the `algorithms` in `scikit learn` do not support `fit_predict_proba` as to my knowledge. Unless you add a method in the source code and build your own version of the algorithm which supports a `fit_predict_proba`. Refer: https://autoimpute.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/autoimpute/imputations/mis_classifier.html

In that link you can see that the `fit_predict_proba` method is implemented.

Comment: As @bg2094 mentioned you to implement these methods in the source code, can you be more specific regarding the estimator that you are using?